# How to update height of my frame?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiwebview

I have `UIScrollView` with a putted into `UIWebView`:

```
    self.scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 64, width: CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), height: CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) - 108))
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = .grayColor()
    self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)

    self.webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGRectGetWidth(self.scrollView.frame), height: CGRectGetHeight(self.scrollView.frame)))
    self.webView.backgroundColor = .orangeColor()
    self.scrollView.addSubview(self.webView)
```

Now, I want to change my `scrollView` and `webView` height. For this I do:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webVieww: UIWebView) {
    self.scrollView.frame.size.height = self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
    self.webView.frame.size.height = self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
}
```

but no luck. It does not change height value of neither `UIScrollView`, nor `UIWebView`.

How can I do it?

Comment: make sure you have clipsToBounds to YES of both webview and scrollview

Answer (score 0):

You can try layoutSubview,like under:
[self.scrollView layoutSubview];
[self.webView layoutSubview];

Answer (score 0):

To update the frames, or height/width - for that matter, you always first set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` and then set the frame as per the requirement. If this doesn't work, then do your changes in the `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`. An example of that would look like this:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
        myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, self.mySecondView.frame.height * 4)
    }
```